# How to use internal flag for wait loop if thread doesn't change state?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

For testing my understanding wait notify I wrote small program which writes `left` `right` in a particular order

```
public class LeftRightWaitNotifyExample {
    final static String str = "1";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        new LeftLegThread(str).start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        new RightLegThread(str).start();
    }
}

class LeftLegThread extends Thread {
    String monitor;

    public LeftLegThread(String str) {
        monitor = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            makeStep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void makeStep() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            int i=0;
            while (i++ < 10) {
                System.out.println("Left ");
                monitor.notify();
                monitor.wait();
            }
        }
    }
}

class RightLegThread extends Thread {
    String monitor;

    public RightLegThread(String str) {
        monitor = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            makeStep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    private void makeStep() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Right ");
                monitor.notify();
                monitor.wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I know that it is bad write following code:

```
 monitor.wait();
```

I should wrap it by loop.

But I cannot imagine loop condition because state doesn't change.

Please, advice how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your program *does* have shared state, you just haven't written it yet.  Your program will not "work" in its current implementation *because the notification could be received by either leg*, so your legs could go in any kind of order (i.e. one could go repeatedly).  the missing "shared state" is "whose turn it is".  each leg should only proceed when it is their turn, then it should pass the turn to the other leg and notify.  your while loop should be based on the current turn value.

Comment: **i.e. one could go repeatedly** it is wrong. I use common monitor. please compile and launch.

Comment: @gstackoverflow - the fun thing about multi-threaded code is that your test cases can "work" and still be completely wrong.  you _can_ have the same leg repeat and otherwise be out of order, but that doesn't necessarily mean that you _will actually_ see this when testing.  multi-threaded code tends to show its bugs when it is stressed (i.e. in production).

Comment: Do you sure? please help rewrite code for getting stressed situation with a high probability

Comment: **final static String str = "1";**   it is shared part of threads

Comment: @gstackoverflow - yes i'm sure.  unfortunately, i'm not sure that there is a way to "force failure" as you would need to artifically delay how java processes a notification.

Comment: without evidence I cannot believe you

Comment: @gstackoverflow - you're welcome to whatever beliefs you choose to hold.  not sure how well that will work out for you in programming in the long run...

Comment: Can you describe situation when my code will not work?

Comment: @gstackoverflow - i already did in my original answer.  i have added emphasis to make it more clear.

Comment: @gstackoverflow - i've described how to solve the problem.  the other answer actually gives you most of the code, other than locking on the wrong object.

Comment: words seems not entirely clear. Code always univocal.

Comment: I don't understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code with some changes which shows how to use notify and wait in loop

```
public class SomeTest {

    public enum Step {
        Left,
        Right
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final AtomicReference<Step> currentStep = new AtomicReference<Step>(Step.Left);

        new LeftLegThread(currentStep).start();
        new RightLegThread(currentStep).start();

        Thread.sleep(10*1000);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class LeftLegThread extends Thread {

    private final AtomicReference<SomeTest.Step> currentStep;


    public LeftLegThread(AtomicReference<SomeTest.Step> str) {
        currentStep = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            makeStep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void makeStep() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (currentStep) {

            while(currentStep.get().equals(SomeTest.Step.Left))
                currentStep.wait();

            currentStep.set(SomeTest.Step.Left);

            currentStep.notify();

        }
    }
}

class RightLegThread extends Thread {
    private final AtomicReference<SomeTest.Step> currentStep;


    public RightLegThread(AtomicReference<SomeTest.Step> str) {
        currentStep = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            makeStep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void makeStep() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (currentStep) {

            while(currentStep.get().equals(SomeTest.Step.Right))
                currentStep.wait();

            currentStep.set(SomeTest.Step.Right);

            currentStep.notify();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this won't work because you are changing the object you are synchronizing *and notifying) on.  you should have one common object for synchronization.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper way to do this is with two locks. For example, one for the right leg and for the left leg. The left thread notifies the right and the right thread notifies the left. (After 10 loop iterations, the code just waits forever. You might want to fix that on your own.)

Your loop condition can simply be switching the legs with an enum.

```
public class Example {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Object left = new Object();
        Object right = new Object();
        LegHolder legHolder = new LegHolder();
        legHolder.leg = Leg.LEFT;
        new LeftLegThread(left, right, legHolder).start();
        new RightLegThread(left, right, legHolder).start();
    }

}

enum Leg {
    LEFT, RIGHT
}

class LegHolder {
    protected volatile Leg leg;
}

class LeftLegThread extends Thread {
    private final Object left;
    private final Object right;
    private final LegHolder holder;

    public LeftLegThread(Object left, Object right, LegHolder holder) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.holder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            while (i++ < 10) {
                synchronized (left) {
                    System.out.println("Left ");
                    synchronized (right) {
                        holder.leg = Leg.RIGHT;
                        right.notify();
                    }
                    while (holder.leg != Leg.LEFT)
                        left.wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class RightLegThread extends Thread {
    final Object left;
    final Object right;
    private final LegHolder holder;

    public RightLegThread(Object left, Object right, LegHolder holder) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.holder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (right) {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Right ");
                    synchronized (left) {
                        holder.leg = Leg.LEFT;
                        left.notify();
                    }
                    while (holder.leg != Leg.RIGHT)
                        right.wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```